# App that limits bandwith usage in certain applications?

Tags: android, bandwidth

My question is how to limit internet speed (Bandwith) usage in certain apps in Android phones.

#### Let’s see the example:

I have three apps (like  App-x, App-Y & App-Z) installed, that need internet connection.

And my bandwith is: 512kbps.

Now I want to devide my bandwith between these three apps.

Something like:

```
AppX=256kbps 
AppY=156kbps 
AppZ=100kbps
```

My device is rooted.

How to do?